# как правильно передать параметр в SqlParam

Tags: c#, python, sql

Как правильно передается параметр

```
_id=23
SqlClient.Main.CreateCommand("select X from TAB where ID= @id", new SqlParam("id", K_{0}), _id)).ExecScalar<int>();
```

получается мне надо на выходе надо смотреть в таблице TAB есть ли там запись в виде К_23, получается надо передать в SqlParam выражение типа K_23. 23 это переменная, которая получаю выше по коду.

Comment: Вам на питоне надо или на шарпе? Уберите лишний тег.

Answer (score -1):

Скажу так, начиная с версии 2.6 у строк появилась хорошая вещь для склейки.

Попробуйте заменить малую часть на "`'K_{}'.format(_id)`".

Надеюсь вам это поможет.